# Is a css transform matrix equivalent to a transform scale, skew, translate

Tags: html, css, transform

Are css **transform matrix** and **transform scale, skew, translate** equivalent?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469502/how-do-i-use-the-matrix-transform-and-other-transform-css-properties) css transform matrix values are equivalent to the rotate, skew and scale functions, however [this post](https://dev.opera.com/articles/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/) makes it seem much more complex...

### matrix(a, b, c, d, e, f)

- arguments **a and d** are for scaling the element. Identical to that of the **scale(a, d)** method.
- arguments **b and c** are for skewing the element. Identical to that of the **skew(b, c)** method.
- arguments **e and f** are for translating the element. Identical to that of the **translate(e, f)** method.

Is the transform matrix actually that simple?

So the following 2 transforms would be identical

```
.scale-in {
  transform: scale(3,3) translate(200px, 200px);  
}
.scale-in-matrix {
  transform: matrix(3, 0, 0, 3, 200, 200); 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not exactly equivalent

CSS transforms are **NOT commutative**. Most mathematic operations are commutative, meaning that the order they are applied doesn't matter. But transforms are **not**. The order is very important, and it is the reason we see different results here when scale and translation is swapped around.

So, the following transform

```
transform: scale(2,2) translate(-100px,-50px);
```

is not equivalent to

```
transform: translate(-100px,-50px) scale(2,2);
```

In the first case, you first zoom, and after that you translate

In the second example we see it move smoother, as it first translates and then scales. Because it first has translated in, the scale is not multiplied in this case, so we can give an equivalent value for the translation

```
transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, -200, -100);
```

is actually equivalent to

```
transform: translate(-200px,-100px) scale(2,2);
```

And this is due to the ordering, in this case they both have the same order, and translation position is not multiplied by the scale.

An updated [codepen example](http://codepen.io/StevenIseki/pen/myPGMW)

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357712/css-transform-matrix-and-equivalent-css-transform-are-different) to a similar question which cleared up the issue, thanks to Vals

Comment: Where does skew fit into all this?