# moving things around with css 2d matrix

Tags: css

Although W3Schools provides quite a lot of information on CSS3, I didn't find much information of what goes where in a 2D Transform matrix.

Please provide information in what goes where in each of the six parameters.

```
div {
    transform: matrix(1, -0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: [The information you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#matrix%28%29)

Comment: @Passerbaly thank you for your answer, but would you mind making an actual answer so users can more easily find the answer? Plus, I kinda want to give you the credit you desserve

Comment: I actually never used this function before, however, reading the guide @Passerby provided, I deduce that `matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty)` means this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkdML.png

simple matrix multiplication.

Comment: Check this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469502/how-do-i-use-the-matrix-transform-and-other-transform-css-properties  another one: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/

Comment: Here they have a generator: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following image as reference:

```
transform:  matrix(a, c, b, d, tx, ty)

a: x scale
c: x skew
b: y skrew
d: y scale
tx: x transition (position)
ty: y transition (position)
```

Very interesting documentation at the following links:

https://dev.opera.com/articles/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/

[image]